# Using Cocos2D Dynamic Texture as background for View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I have a **dynamic texture** I created with `CCRenderTexture`.  I would like to use it in the top half of one of the View Controllers in an app.

Currently I have:

- One app with a **ViewController that has two UIButtons** on it
- One app where with the **dynamic texture** was built (similar to this
  tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/3857/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture)

So I need to take the dynamic texture, and place it as the upper 25% of the View Controller in the app that has the two `UIButton`s in the View Controller.

How would I go about doing this?  Do I need to somehow subview the View Controller that has the two `UIButton`s?  I'm assuming I would put the dynamic texture as a background somehow, and then lay the view with the two `UIButton`s on top of it.  But I'm not totally sure.

Comment: best to use a cocos2d sprite and make the view controller's view transparent (opaque = NO). Or use render textures getUIImage method: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_render_texture.html   note this is a costly operation

Comment: I see, I'll give it a shot today then.  Thanks for the detailed answer, appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per LearnCocos2D response above, I followed his advice: best to use a cocos2d sprite and make the view controller's view transparent (opaque = NO). Or use render textures getUIImage method: learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/… note this is a costly operation